# Issue with Modals not firing inside of iDangero.us swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modal-dialog, swiper.js

I am using the iDangerous.us Swiper and running into an issue where I can't trigger any events inside of the swiper-wrapper. I am trying to fire a modal inside of each slide and nothing happens.

Any Modal I have placed inside of the swiper-wrapper will not function. I can't figure out if this is a javascript issue or a css z-index issue. I have tried multiple different Modals and they all seem to have the same effect. The Modal will work once it is outside of the swiper-wrapper element. I even tried a pure css modal and same issue, it will only fire outside of the swiper-wrapper element.

It looks like elements are cloned to make the slider work, which could potentially be killing the event listeners that are being set up.

I thought it could be an issue with the modal plugin I am using, but like I said I tried multiple different methods, including bootstrap's out of the box modal and a pure css implementation, and still no luck.

link to site:

http://bigredsun.staging.wpengine.com/our-work-index/

The 'Read More' button is the buttons that is supposed to trigger a popup modal.

Here is what I am doing:

https://gist.github.com/Jessekevon/8b694cc182a04610de16

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Definitely not a z-index issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the 'position: fixed' property inside elements with transforms. If you render the modal outside the Swiper, it should work

Resources:

- https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4093